# Try to display data using Mobx from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, store, mobx

Im making React app that shows coins' data from API.
I did it with `useEffect` and it works fine, but now I'm trying to do the same using Mobx.
Im trying to create a store file that gets the data from an API and stores it, then passes it to App.js and then displays the data on screen.

Im new with Mobx. Please help me resolving my Issue

**This is my useEffect:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false')
      .then(res => {
        setCoins(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, []);
```

How can I convert this useEffect to Mobx in Store.js file?
For the first step I just want to display coins' name.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow DorCo! This is not a code writing service, so please try write some code yourself and come back if you have a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The structure should look like this one:

```js
// Coins Store file
type Coin = {
  name: string;
}

export class CointStore {
  // not sure what is your coins data type, lets assume this is array 
  readonly coins = observable<Coin>([]);

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  getCoins() {
    return axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets')
       .then(response => this.coins.replace(response.data);
  }
}
```

...

```js
// this is app.js file

import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite'
import {createContext, useContext, useEffect} from "react"
import {CointStore} from './CointStore'

const CoinsContext = createContext<CointStore>()

const CoinsView = observer(() => {
  const coinStore = useContext(CoinsContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    coinStore.getCoins()
  }, []);

  return (
    <span>
      {coinStore.coins.map(coin => <span>{coin.name}</span>)}
    </span>
  )
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <CoinsContext.Provider value={new CointStore()}>
    <CoinsView />
  </CoinsContext.Provider>,
  document.body
)
```